# use the AFNetworking 3.0, my app have some memory leaks

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I use the AFNetworking 3.0 in my app, memory leaks were discovered。
codes:

```
        let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
        manager.POST("", parameters: nil, progress: { (progress:NSProgress) in

        }, success: { (task:NSURLSessionDataTask, objects:AnyObject?) in

    }) { (task:NSURLSessionDataTask?, error:NSError) in

    }

+ (instancetype)manager {
    return [[[self class] alloc] initWithBaseURL:nil];
}
```

New object is created each calls，the `manager` is not a singleton.
Is this causes a memory leak？

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the cause.

You have to handle the first created object, and then return it if initialized.

Example :

```
static MyClass *_instance = nil;
+ (instancetype)manager {
    if (_instance == nil) {
       _instance = [[[self class] alloc] initWithBaseURL:nil];
    }
    return _instance
}
```

Comment: in the framework ,`NSURLSessionTask` have some observers,I'm not sure whether can do it.

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking 3.0  is not suitable for Swift programming. 
There is a pretty nicely Networking framework that perfectly support Swift.
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

In Objective-C, you code should be below.

```
let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
    manager.POST("http://www.google.com/", parameters: nil, progress: { (progress:NSProgress) in

    }, success: { (task:NSURLSessionDataTask, objects:AnyObject?) in

}) { (task:NSURLSessionDataTask?, error:NSError) in

}

func getManager() -> AFHTTPSessionManager
{
     if manager == nil {
         let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
     }
     return manager;
}
```

Comment: but，the alamofire cant use in ios7.